# What is the purpose of the Ember.Container

Tags: ember.js

Can anyone explain what the purpose of the Container module is in the latest Ember?

An example of its usage, in the setup and in the start of this test:

```
module("Ember.View - handlebars integration", {
  setup: function() {
    Ember.lookup = lookup = { Ember: Ember };
    lookup.TemplateTests = TemplateTests = Ember.Namespace.create();

    container = new Ember.Container();
    container.optionsForType('template', { instantiate: false });
  }

test("template view should call the function of the associated template", function() {
  container.register('template', 'testTemplate', Ember.Handlebars.compile("<h1 id='twas-called'>template was called</h1>"));
```

Comment: I think (and hope) this will be documented. I know @tchak has worked on this, perhaps he could give an explanation here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The goal of the container is to provide a more general-purpose mechanism for describing module dependencies than the ad-hoc approach we had been using.

For example, imagine you want to find the controller for the `post` route. The default Ember rules are that we would look it up as `App.PostController`. Before the container, we would just hardcode those rules wherever we needed to do the lookup (using `classify` and friends).

The container provides a way for us to define those rules in a single place. As a bonus, the rules can be overridden for applications that want a different convention.

So instead of `Ember.get(namespace, Ember.String.classify(name) + 'Controller')` internally, we now do `container.lookup('controller:' + name)`.

Comment: But as I understand this is used only for internal API, not a public one, right?

Answer (score 2):

Intended for internal use.

Not meant to be public API

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/5becdc4467573f80a5c5dbb51d97c6b9239714a8

Comment: Parts of Container are somewhat public and can (should) be used to register / lookup / inject dependencies. The commit you've linked talks about #controllerFor. I.e. you should not access the container when there are already public mechanisms to do so (Ember abstracts away these dependency injections). ["Public api for the container is still in flux."](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/container/lib/main.js)