# How can access controllers from normal class in Ember.pre4 version?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

Until now I usually had a datasource class that contained all the functionality to access the servers, retrieve the data and put it the controllers, similar to this:

```
...
App.DataSource = Ember.Object.extend({
  getBooks: function(callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/books.json',
      done: function(data){
        //process the data
        App.get('router.booksController').set('content', processedData);
      }
    });
  }
});

App.dataSource = App.DataSource.create();
...
```

But since the released of pre-4 version the controllers cannot be longer accessed from the router, and it seems like the access to them is very restricted, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506275/accessing-an-instance-of-a-controller-or-a-view-in-ember) question.

So according to these changes, is this not possible anymore? What is the recommended way?

Comment: You should consider using [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) for loading stuff from server.

Comment: That would be the last option, I don't want to rewrite all the adapters and server api just to upgrade to a non relase version of ember...

Answer (score 1):

The router has a new method controllerFor which takes the string name of the controller instance.  As long as you can get a reference to the router, you should be able to access the controllers which are instantiated / generated by ember.

See: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/

You might still be able to do something like `App.Router.controllerFor("books")` although hard coding that within your object which is behaving like a model would not be good.

Another odd thing I noticed is that Ember.Router is no longer in the websites API to look up documentation. I think this is because they moved the core of the router to an independent project which Ember extends or something like that.

I think this is the github source: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would say you're using Ember incorrectly in this sense. It seems odd to me in having your `App.DataSource` object be aware of a controller. Two important questions to ask yourself:

1. Why does this object have the responsibility of populating the controller?
2. Why doesn't the controller have the responsibility of populating itself?

**@Matt:** I've been using the `this.controllerFor` method as well, but it has since been deprecated. Instead we should be using the `needs` approach:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    // Requires App.ThisController, App.ThatController.
    needs: ['this', 'that']
});
```

In this case, I would give `BooksController` the responsibility of populating itself. Maybe in the `init` method.

If you **really** need to use `App.DataSource` then you really need to think of another way to do this.

Comment: of course the controller is the one who decides to call the datasource method, but I wanted to keep all the logic that relates to making external calls to the server together for the sake of clarity, did't want to have all the ajax calls spread through the code. And even removing the Datasource class still a problem remains, the calls to the server are async, so somehow, they must be able to get back to the controller and to push the data when is ready