# ContainerView: limitations when dynamically adding views

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**`ContainerView.pushObject()` does not automatically wire-up dynamically added views with a `Container` object.**
The lack of an auto-wired container causes a render failure when a view renders a template that contains a handlebars render helper.

**SIMPLE CASE THAT WORKS (KIND OF)**

View:

```js
App.DynamicView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'dynamic',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var control = this.get('controller');
        control.send( 'view_inserted',  this.templateName, control._debugContainerKey);
        control.send('callDynamicController');
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dynamic">
    dynamic
</script>
```

Controller (only used when manually assigned):

```js
App.DynamicController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    className: 'App.DynamicWithRenderController',
        callDynamicController: function() {
            console.log('DynamicController.callDynamicController()');
    }
});
```

Index Controller:

```js
App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    view_inserted: function(aview, acontroller) { 
        console.log('view inserted!', aview, acontroller);
    }
})
```

Instantiation code:

```js
var acontainer = App.DynamicController.create({});
var aview = App.DynamicView.create({ controller: acontroller })
acontainerView.pushObject(aview);
```

These classes render & behave as expected, **but** if you interogate them, lack some of the Ember-wiring (e.g. no `_debugContainerKey` & `container` properties IIRC):

**MORE ADVANCED CASE THAT BREAKS**

If we introduce a handlebars template that uses rendering helpers, it breaks rendering. The dynamically added view currently lacks some properties the rendering helper assumes

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dynamic-with-render">
    dynamic w/render:
    {{render knob}}
</script>
```

and make knob look like this:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="knob">
    &#123;&#123;render knob&#125;&#125;
</script>
```

The (failing) dynamic view instantiation code:

```js
var acontainer = App.DynamicController.create({});
var aview = App.DynamicView.create({ 
    controller: acontroller, 
    template:'dynamic-with-render' })
acontainerView.pushObject(aview);
```

**CODE EXAMPLE**

A fuller example with some notes can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/AshCoolman/KyJ2U/6/embedded/result/

NOTE: My tests include a custom handlebars helper based of the *control* helper called *controlWithVars*

**THE PROBLEM**

It looks like I need to write something that does the Ember-wiring, in either:

1. the more native ContainerView (getting into the Ember guts), OR
2. a more de-coupled new render helper possibly inelegant)

I'm not sure how to proceed. It would be great if someone has already come up with an elegant solution, or at least could give me some helpful tips.

EDIT: So it looks like creating and assigning a container, which includes the views dependencies might be a solution. Thoughts anyone?

**HELPFUL READING**

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2108

[What is the purpose of the Ember.Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085749/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-ember-container)

http://mcdowall.info/posts/ember-application-initializers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raison d'être of `Ember.ContainerView` is for dynamically adding and removing views, so I'm pretty confident you can do all the things you want to with it.

One thing I noticed in your examples is that you are creating your child views with `View.create(attrs)`. It is important to use `containerView.createChildView(viewClassName, attrs)` to create views that get the container, parent view hierarchy, and more. See the implementation more details:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L2072

Comment: I bumped into the same problem. Tried to add the view (which contains a linkTo helper) with createChildView(viewClassName, attrs), empty attr, but i get the same error.

Comment: AshleyCoolman or @EduárdMoldován - do either of you have a jsfiddle or something illustrating this issue?

Comment: @EduárdMoldován Here's a simple fix http://jsbin.com/iwuyol/3/edit. The root cause here is that when you create the ContainerView and append it, you are bypassing the router's rendering. It would be better to embed a custom container view in the application template.