# Can I call other controller's method in Ember?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

In my Ember app I have an `ArrayController` inside of which I've created a method:

```
App.SwatchesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  push: function (color) {
    var model = this.get('model');
    /* do a few things */
    this.set('model', model);
  }
});
```

When I'm trying to call this method from an action inside `ApplicationCotroller`, I get a `TypeError`:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    parse: function () {
      App.SwatchesController.push('#fff'); // TypeError: Object function (){/* long body here */} has no method 'push' 
    }
  }
});
```

**Is a controller method is something I should be using in Ember?** Unfortunately, official docs provide only limited examples on controllers.

I probably could define model as `App.Swatches` and manage it directly from `ApplicationController`, but I believe I shouldn't, because that what `SwatchesController` is for.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/UToDazI/3/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try using the following code in your `ApplicationController`?

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: "swatches",
    swatchesController: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.swatches"),
    actions: {
        parse: function () {
            var swatchesController = this.get('swatchesController');
            swatchesController.push('#fff');
        }
    }
});
```

Managing dependencies between controllers is mentioned [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

Comment: Got `ReferenceError: swatchesController is not defined`, tried `this.swatches.Controller` - same.

Comment: Apologies. I just edited the code in my answer -- I introduced the variable `swatchesController` corrrectly. Let me know if this works.

Comment: As in Edu's answer I got `TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'get'` when trying to get model inside `push`.

Comment: Which line does the error point to? That might throw more light on the issue.

Comment: `var model = this.get('model');` I've added a demo to my question, maybe it will help.

Comment: I cloned your JS Bin post [here](http://jsbin.com/UrAtITe/1/edit), and edited it to include the changes I've mentioned; it seems to be working fine. The `push` method seems to be invoked, and I see some output on the console too.

Comment: There are no more errors, but I still can't see the result displayed. `{{this.model}}` inside `swatches` template show nothing (http://jsbin.com/UrAtITe/2/edit?html,js,output), so I believe we setting the wrong `model`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is based on the Jackil's response

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  source:null,
  needs: "swatches",
  swatchesController: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.swatches"),
  actions: {
    parse: function () {
      var source = this.get('source');
      source.split(',').forEach(function (color) {
        this.get('swatchesController').addObject({color:color.trim()});
      },this);
    }
  }
});

App.SwatchesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

template also modified

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="swatches">
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>{{color}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

Two points:

- General Js, inside forEach there is a change in the scope, you can send second parameter to set tha **this** variable, the *TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'get'* was inside the forEach...
- In ember is better to use the suplied api functions, in the array controller we have the addObject, this way the bindings are informed and the layout updates acordingly

JsBin http://jsbin.com/UToDazI/6/

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks so much for not giving up. I think it will be fair if I accept Jackell's answer, but I'm planing to reward your answer with a bounty when eligible.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate the controller prior to call its methods... In your code App.SwatchesController is a class that extends from other class, not an instance...

Something like

```
App.swatchesController = App.SwatchesController.create({});
```

And then you can call the method on the instantiated controller, the non capilazed one...

```
  parse: function () {
     App.swatchesController.push('#fff'); 
  }
```

Comment: This way when I try to get `model` property I got `TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'get'`.

Comment: However the way to go is what @Jackail suggested in his response, is the ember way to let the framework instantiate the controllers, views etc...

Comment: I agree with your comment Edu that you should let the framework handle the instantiation of objects for you. Here's Yehuda's short explanation of the container (Ember's dependency headquarters): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085749/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-ember-container#answer-14089090