# Accepted practice to reset a bunch of controllers

Tags: ember.js

In several situations in my App I need to reset a bunch of controllers (in ajax replies, ...). This happens at different points in the application, so I do not have always a route/controller/view available. I want to have a single easy-to-use function to reset everything, no parameters needed.

This is what I am trying to replace (very old version of ember):

```
function resetApp() {
  Dashboard.router.totalCallsController.set("content", 0);
  Dashboard.router.totalMinutesController.set("content", 0);
  Dashboard.router.callDurationAvgController.set("content", 0);
};
```

And now I am doing:

```
function resetApp() {
  var container = Dashboard.__container__;
  container.lookup('controller:totalCalls').set("content", 0);
  container.lookup('controller:totalMinutes').set("content", 0);
  container.lookup('controller:callDurationAvg').set("content", 0);
}
```

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089090/647991) the container should not be used for that. How can I get a controller if I only have access to the application object? Before it was just easy: in Dasboard.router we could access all controllers directly. Now only via the **container**, but this is not advised, and probably will change (API is n flux). So what can I do?

Comment: I agree, the container shouldn't be used, but I doubt they'll ever change it again since it hit 1.0.  Is this is a global function?  Where does it need to be called from?

Comment: Global, and must be called at several points in the application

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for the most Emberish way, but want the function to live outside of Ember, I would suggest the observer pattern. In an essence anytime a controller is created you subscribe it to the global reset function.  There are a few ways to accomplish this, I'd probably do it with a mixin.

Here's a small example:

```
App.ResettableMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
  init: function(){
    this._super(); 
    App.Resettable.join(this.get('resetMe'), this);
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend(App.ResettableMixin,{
  resetMe: function(){
    console.log('reset index controller');
  }
});


App.FooController = Em.ObjectController.extend(App.ResettableMixin,{
  resetMe: function(){
    console.log('reset foo controller ' + this.get('model'));
  }
});

App.Resettable = {
  resetters: [],

  join: function(methodToCall, context){
    this.resetters.push({method: methodToCall, context:context});
  },

  reset: function(){
    var item;
    console.log('resetting ' + this.resetters.length + ' items');
    for(var i = 0, len = this.resetters.length; i<len;i++){
      item = this.resetters[i];
      item.method.apply(item.context); 
    }
  },

  remove: function(methodToFind){
   // iterate through find, and remove it from resetters
  }
};
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hudugene/4/edit